# How to use React Hooks to set state only at any first page visited by user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React Hooks and I need to set a state the very first page a user visits, and it must persist.

Right now I'm doing like this:

```
const Routes = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(StoreContext);
  useEffect(async () => {
    const rates = await updateRates();
    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_RATE", payload: rates });
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={favicon} />
      <Route path="/" component={navbar} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={() => <h1>App</h1>} />
        <Route path="*" component={() => <h1>Page not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

This is in my `routes.js` file. However this makes the state updates every other page the user visits. E.g., if user visits `Main`, then `SignIn`, the state is updated upon rendering `Main` and then updated again while rendering `SignIn`.

I tried to put in my `App.js` file, however it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be getting a warning, as useEffect expects you to return a cleanup callback, and not a promise.  Also what you asking for sounds better served with `localStorage or sessionStorager`, depending if you want to persist after browser close.

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving a warning. How should I just store the state in `sessionStorage` once, and don't update every page?